# Calculate the exact UTC offset with DST in mind?

Tags: android, timezone, utc, dst

On `Android`, it seems there is no API to easily get the local time. Digging through the net, I found some code to calculate the offset from the `UTC` time using the `TimeZone` class:

```
final long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(timestamp);
if (TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) {
    offset = offset - TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings();
}
```

Now, this code is pretty much what I need, but it soon becomes clear that the formula is wrong. E.g. For `CET` the offset becomes 3600000, but for `CEST` it would be 0 - which is wrong (should be 7200000).

Obviously, I can patch the code to use addition instead of subtraction, but I'm not sure this is safe since the original author explicitly stated that the subtraction was needed (I think it was for `PST`).

**How do I make my formula work for all time zones?**

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to simply get the local time?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to get an exact UTC offset for the phone's local time.